# Firefox personas: Keep title bar default (transparent on Windows 7)

Tags: firefox, aero, personas

In firefox, is there a way to apply personas to everywhere **but** the titlebar? I quite like the aero glass look of the default theme, but I would like to apply some personas to the rest of the window.

Is it possible at all?

Edit: Below is a picture of the area I would like the personas to leave transparent[image]:

Comment: Can you create a photoshop of the desired result and point out which parts should be themed and which should be transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but i think you will need to create your own persona. Personas are realy simple its kinda just an image with added transparency.

Found this youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_CVAKPdpHA if you want to create one yourself.

Comment: Or just use one that allready exists https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/transparent-firefox/